# Flattening index in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to the python and I have been playing around with Panda dataframes, but when I use a groupby, I am not longer able to iterate over the dataframes using the labels.

Can some help me ?

```
newDF=df[df['Currency'].str.contains(currency)&df['Description'].str.contains('fx')]
newDF=newDF.rename(index=str, columns={ "Paid": "Withdrawn"})

moneyWithdrawnByUserDF=pd.DataFrame(newDF.groupby(['FirstName'])[['Withdrawn']].sum())

for index,row in moneyWithdrawnByUserDF.iterrows():
  print row['FirstName']
```

The output/error I got is below :

```
Index([u'Email', u'FirstName', u'LastName', u'Owed', u'Withdrawn', u'UserId',

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "main.py", line 416, in <module>

sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))

File "main.py", line 412, in main

parseGroups()

   u'Category', u'Description', u'Id', u'Currency', u'Cost', u'Details',

   u'GroupId'],

  dtype='object')

 File "main.py", line 45, in parseGroups

parseGroup(group) 

  File "main.py", line 81, in parseGroup processCurrencies(df)

  File "main.py", line 95, in processCurrencies processCurrency(df, currency)

  File "main.py", line 105, in processCurrency   moneyWithdrawnByUserDF=calculateMoneyWithdrawnByUser(df, currency)

 File "main.py", line 319, in calculateMoneyWithdrawnByUser

print row['FirstName']

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 601, in __getitem__

result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2491, in get_value

  raise e1

 KeyError: 'FirstName'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you need change:

```
moneyWithdrawnByUserDF=pd.DataFrame(newDF.groupby(['FirstName'])[['Withdrawn']].sum())
```

by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
moneyWithdrawnByUserDF= newDF.groupby(['FirstName'])['Withdrawn'].sum().reset_index()
```

Or parameter `as_index=False` for `DataFrame`:

```
moneyWithdrawnByUserDF= newDF.groupby(['FirstName'], as_index=False)['Withdrawn'].sum()
```